# 22.04 Can't Install - Black Screen

Tags: boot, nvidia, usb

Bootable 22.04 USB Created using Rufus.

Menu option appears

Tried Normal and Safe GFX Option

Logo shows for a short while then screen goes blank.

Same issue on laptop and PC.

PC NVidia 2080Ti, Laptop Nvidia 2060/Intel dual Gfx

Same USB stick and same Rufus tool settings used to create EndeavourOS bootable USB which installs fine, so this rules out faulty USB stick+ USB Port

Waited a long time on the laptop and it eventually came up but was so slow to respond it was unusable. Double clicking on the installer took about 5 minutes to respond. That was in safe gfx mode.

Comment: Sorry that does not rule out the USB. A USB can write one file fine and then good bad they are short term storage devices of different quality. Did you verify the Ubuntu download before making the Boot USB? https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-verify-ubuntu#1-overview

Comment: Looks like a Wayland/NVidia issue judging from the behaviour. I probably just need to switch to xorg until I get Ubuntu installed, install NVidia binaries, then switch back again. To answer your question, no I didn't verify, and you do raise a good point.